# Rectangle X axis move issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, rect

I was just doing random stuff with GUI and I came to this issue.When I press right arrow key, rectangle really moves on X axis, but distance moved is not constant.It's raising pretty fast and rectangle does after each press bigger moves.In my recent code line `X=X+1` seemed to work pretty fine.Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Buffer extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
public static JFrame frame;
public int x;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x,0,20,20);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
}




public static void main(String args[]){
    Buffer z=new Buffer();

    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.add(z);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        x=x+1;
        repaint();
    }

}
    }
```

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: Expanding on Andrew's comment you can also check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line from `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`

```
frame.addKeyListener(this);
```

and add the following line to `public static void main(String args[])`

```
frame.addKeyListener(z);
```

The problem was that after every `repaint();` through the `keyPressed` method, the `paintComponent` method added a new `KeyListener` to your frame.
But if you have several `KeyListeners`, every Listener will invoke the `keyPressed` method for the same event. So if you have 5 Listeners and you press the right arrow once, the `keyPressed` method is invoked five times and x is incremented by five.
That meant that the rectangle moved with every hit of the right arrow a bit faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try `keyReleased` instead of `keyPressed`. It may be so that while the key is pressed, it keeps invoking the `keyPressed` event.

Comment: This is not the way to go!  Some systems (AFAIR L*nux based)  will fire the key pressed/key released event multiple times if the key is held down.